# Constructor to receive three parameters in java?

Tags: java, constructor

Im doing a project for course and they want the "second constructor to receive three parameters, `ProductName`, `Price` and `Quantity`. These parameters must be assigned to the correct instance variables of the class, also increase `OrderNum` variable by one.

I'm wondering if this is right?

```
public Order(String ProductName, double Price, int Quantity){
     //calling from parameter 
    this.ProductName = ProductName;
    this.Quantity = Quantity;
    this.Price = Price;
    OrderNum++;
}
```

Comment: Your code is correct, i don´t see any problem.

Comment: Aside from the variable names and the presumably mutable static variable, no problem there.

Comment: The assignment has the variable names start with a lowercase character, but you start with an uppercase character. Given that both the Java coding conventions and the assignment say "lowercase", I'd say your code is wrong on that point.

Comment: You do not show whether `OrderNum` is static or not.

Comment: I assume that the `orderNum` is to count every order placed in your application. This variable should be declared as `static`.

Comment: Bad design. You incremented `OrderNum` in the constructor, but where do you decrease it? Some `dispose` method? Otherwise, sooner or later that variable is going to be meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your syntax is correct.

I would just advise to use camelCase in your variables since it's the convention in Java. Also use 'this' for increasing the OrderNum of your object ( i. e. `this.orderNumber++;` ). This way will be clear that you are increasing the order number of your object.

Comment: Nit: OP's variable names are already in camel case - they're just in UpperCamelCase. You are suggesting they should be in lowerCamelCase.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly your problem, the constructor seemingly is correct.

But the OrderNum increment is only aplicate to the actual instance, not for all instances. Maybe you send previous OrderNum as a parameter.